# centos 6.4, sudo -u -H doesn't work

Tags: sudo, centos6

I have problems using some commands from `sudo`.

I tried below command on Centos 6.4 and got an error.

```
sudo -u someuser -H bundle install
sudo: bundle: command not found
```

However when I try same command on Ubuntu 14.04 it works fine.

Not only `bundle` but also many commands get same error. For example `ruby, node`. However some commands work fine. For example `echo, mkdir, touch ...`

Anyone have some ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`secure_path` in `/etc/sudoers` ensures that your path is clean when running binaries under sudo.
In CentOS you should have something like

```
Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

That explains why some commands are found (echo, mkdir, touch ...).

You can keep your environment variables (as $PATH)
in this form

```
sudo -u someuser "PATH=$PATH" bundle install
```

From `man sudo`

> Environment variables to be set for the command may also be passed on
>   the command line in the form of VAR=value, e.g.
>   LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/pkg/lib.  Variables passed on the command
>   line are subject to the same
>        restrictions as normal environment variables with one important exception.  If the setenv option is set in sudoers, the command to be
>   run has the SETENV tag set or the command matched is ALL, the user may
>   set variables
>        that would otherwise be forbidden.  See sudoers(5) for more information.

Depending on your system's security policy, you could use `-E` instead of the method written above.

> -E          The -E (preserve environment) option indicates to the security policy that the user wishes to preserve their existing
>   environment variables.  The security policy may return an error if the
>   -E option is specified and the user does not have permission to preserve the environment.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I fix this issue by modifing sudoers.       `Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin => Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin`